# несколько циклов php

Tags: php, mysql, циклы

Здравствуйте. У меня имеется таблица с товаром в базе в ней строчки `id`, `waybill_id`, `name`, `date` (идентификатор, номер продажи, товар, дата). Поле `id` уникально, а номер продажи повторяется, когда продано несколько товаров за раз.

Имеется простой код, который все это выводит:

```
$todbprod = $mysqli->query('SELECT id, waybill_id, name, date FROM `waybills`');

while($row = $todbprod->fetch_array()) {
    echo "ИД: ".$row['id']."\n";
    echo "ИДП: ".$row['waybill_id']."\n";
    echo "Товар: ".$row['name']."<hr>\n";
}
```

Выводит каждую строчку хорошо. Но хочется сгруппировать еще и по номеру продажи. Чтобы было: продажа `waybill_id`, внутри товары, следующая продажа `waybill_id`.
Получается нужен еще один цикл, внутри него прописать, но я не совсем соображу, как правильно его вывести.

Сейчас выводится так:

```
 - продажа 01, товар 01
 - продажа 01, товар 02
 - продажа 01, товар 03
 - продажа 02, товар 01
```

А хочется привести к списку:

```
 - продажа 01
   -товар 01
   -товар 02
   -товар 03
 - продажа 02
```

Comment: Читайте про ORDER BY http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/Sorting_rows.html

Comment: `SELECT id, waybill_id, name, date FROM waybills GROUP BY waybill_id ORDER BY waybill_id ASC`

Answer (score 1):

С точностью до синтаксиса:

```
$todbprod = $mysqli->query('SELECT id, waybill_id, name, date FROM waybills order by 2,1');

while ($row = $todbprod->fetch_array()) {
    if ($waybill_id == $row['waybill_id']) {
        echo "\nИДП: " . $row['waybill_id'] . "\n\n";
    }

    echo "ИД: ".$row['id']."\n";
    echo "Товар: ".$row['name']."<hr>\n";

    $waybill_id = $row['waybill_id'];
}
```

Comment: с этим кодом почему то все равно в каждой строке все переменные выводит

Comment: Заменил "=" на "==" (мог бы и сам поправить, кстати) - пробуй.